# NameError: global name 'category' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am making a Hangman Game and having trouble. Ok every time I go to edit this and save my edits I get a red mark saying I need more details not just code so this is my more details. Please do not delete it or I cannot edit my post. :)

My error is,

> "NameError: global name 'category' is not defined"

```
#Hangman Game V1 by (My name)

import random
import time

play_again = 'Yes'

#Categorys

animals = ['alligator', 'barracuda', 'cougar', 'cheetah', 'dolphin',      'falcon', 'gorilla', 'penguin', 'salmon', 'wombat']

olympics = ['archery', 'badminton', 'cycling', 'rowing', 'fencing', 'gymnastics', 'sailing', 'tennis', 'swimming',
            'volleyball']

countries = ['china', 'america', 'mexico', 'russia', 'sweden', 'canada', 'spain', 'korea', 'japan', 'france']


def intro():
    print ''
    print 'Welcome to Hangman by (My name)!'
    print ''
    print ''


def pick_category():
    category = raw_input('First, choose a category by typing in it\'s name. Your options are: Animals, Olympics, & '\
                         'Countries!')
    print ''
    print 'You chose the category ' + category + '.'
    return category

def choose_word():
    print ''
    print 'Now I will pick the secret word from your category.'
    print ''
    print '...'
    time.sleep(1)

    if category == 'Animals':
        secret_word = random.choice(animals)

    if category == 'Olympics':
        secret_word = random.choice(olympics)

    if category == 'Countries':
        secret_word = random.choice(countries)

    print ''
    print 'Alright, I have chosen the word!'
    #for testing purposes
    print secret_word
```

while play_again: 
     intro()
     pick_category()
     choose_word()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! No need to explain you are new, or what you've worked on so far. Just explain the problem at hand and hopefully someone will assist you. Also - Python is hard to format. Please [edit] if I messed something up.

Comment: @cricket_007 I believe you reformatted my original question or the site did that automatically? Either way I can't quite tell, did you change the code at all or just reformat it?

Comment: I did attempt to reformat, yes. I think that while loop at the buttom needs to be un-indented though

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh i see. Yes in my actual code it is not indented. I'm not sure what went on there.

Comment: where is that `category` in `choose_word`  function ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant for *category* to be an argument of `choose_word()`. At the moment `pick_category()` returns the value of the local variable *category*, which is then ignored. Instead define `choose_word()` as:

```
def choose_word(category):
    ...
```

and pass the returned category to it, for example like this:

```
while play_again: 
    intro()
    # Passes the returned category as the argument
    choose_word(pick_category())
```

Comment: From the way I interpreted what you said to change. This is what my code is.
   def choose_word(pick_category):
    if category == 'Animals':
        secret_word = random.choice(animals)
        return secret_word
    if category == 'Olympics':
        secret_word = random.choice(olympics)
        return secret_word
    if category == 'Countries':
        secret_word = random.choice(countries)
        return secret_word
        print 'Alright, I have chosen the word!'
while play_again:
    intro()
    pick_category()
    choose_word(pick_category())

Comment: I had to shorten it and cut out the text to make it fit. I really don't know what I am doing sorry the format in that comment is god awful. Basically I changed the def choose_word() to def choose_word(pick_category) then in the final code in the bottom I changed it to intro(), then, pick_category, and last choose_word(pick_category())

Comment: You named the argument *pick_category*, but the variable you're trying to use is still *category*, which is still undefined. Name the argument *category*.

Comment: I changed the argument to just category and the correction squiggles went away. I tested the code and this is what I see after the intro. First, choose a category by typing in it's name. Your options are: Animals, Olympics, & Countries!Animals

You chose the category Animals.
First, choose a category by typing in it's name. Your options are: Animals, Olympics, & Countries!

Comment: the issue is it asks twice when it shouldn't in simpler terms

Comment: You're calling the function twice, ignoring the first result.

Comment: I removed the first pick_category. Now I see the choose_word is not continuing. It looks like this.     Now I will pick the secret word from your category.

...

Comment: That is beyond this Q/A. Please ask a new question with a proper problem definition. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: very well then. I am just looking for how to make my code work so I can move on to the next steps. Anyways, thank you for your help

Comment: Just a pointer: your choices are capitalized. Is your input? *secret_word* will not be defined, if a wrong input is given and thus you should get again a `NameError`, this time for *secret_word*.